# How can a property resolve its own name and type with reflection?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, properties

Is there a way for a property to access its own name and type at runtime using reflection? I want to access this info without hard coding the name or index of the property in the class.

Simple Example Code:

```
Private ReadOnly Property MyProperyName() As String
    Get
        Console.WriteLine((Get Current Property Info).Type.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine((Get Current Property Info).Name)
        Return ""
    End Get
End Property
```

Expected output:

```
System.String
MyPropertyName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `StackTrace` to get the current method:

```
Dim currentMethod = CType(new StackTrace(0, false).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), _ 
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
```

If you can assume that you're in a property, then you can strip the "get_" off of the front of the method name:

```
Dim propertyName as string = currentMethod.Name.SubString(4)
```

And use `ReturnType` for the property type:

```
Dim propertyType as Type = currentMethod.ReturnType
```